# Error - AccessDenied on https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I made the app in multiple tenants. When I am trying to use Ms Graph Api I am getting this error on selected endpoints for personal account users. However, organization users are working with no errors.

Error - AccessDenied on https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

How to allow the Azure app to get information on login from personal account users.

> Here is the code i used 
>   [Tried code Link here](https://paste.ofcode.org/?edit=FPZ454ejxv2n8Y8Zi87i6j)

Comment: Post the code on how you get the token

Comment: @Boominathan - Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include any relevant code, specific errors, etc. in your question itself, not as an external link (you'll need to edit your question). Further: Please don't call out to people to see if there's around, and reading your updates; this isn't a support site with given time-windows for answering - it's just volunteers answering programming questions.